# Are getters for objects any different than ones for primitives?

Tags: java, methods, get, return-value

Should getters just return the object:

```
public MyObject getMyObject() {
    return myObject;
}
```

Or should it make a copy of the object it's returning and return the copy?

```
public MyObject getMyObject() {
    MyObject tempObject;
    // call setters to set its attributes
    return tempObject;
}
```

High school "CS" courses here aren't detailed enough. My teacher never talked about classes, objects, and references.

Comment: It depends on what you want it to do.  Perhaps the object should be immutable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on what you're trying to do.

In general, though, you just want a reference to the object, and you use your first code example. For example, Swing components have a method called `getTopLevelAncestor()`. It's completely useless to have a copy of the parent component--what's wanted is a reference to the child's actual parent.

Returning a copy is not standard, and should only be used under very specific (and well-documented) circumstances. Other people using your code will not expect to get copies of objects.

Answer (score 3):

The only difference is that while returned primitives are "immutable" by nature, returning an object directly like this could allow the caller to change properties on it (assuming that `MyObject` is mutable), possibly affecting the internals of your class's implementation.  (Code analysis tools like FindBugs check for exactly this.  Primitives are actually mutable, but when returned from a class, there is no way to update the class's value through the returned primitive.)  That considered, it's usually a safer bet to return a copy / clone - understanding there may be a performance penalty involved in doing this.

With whatever option you choose, please document what your class or individual methods do using Javadoc.

Comment: Primitives are not immutable. I guess that what you meant was that primitive values returned by a getter cannot be used to mutate the containing object.

Comment: @SkipHead:  You're right, but in the context of, say, if you were calling a method from an object and retrieved a primitive, you couldn't change the value you get from that primitive unless you used a corresponding mutator.  If I had some method that returned `10` every time, no matter what I did to it (unless I mutated it in the object), I'd still get `10` back.

Comment: The performance penalty of making a copy can be much more than "slight", particularly if only a deep copy would insulate MyObject from changes in the returned object. Sometimes it makes no sense to return a copy (e.g., the returned object is supposed to be a singleton). The default recommendation should _not_ be to return a copy. It should be: "If returning a direct reference to an internal object might be dangerous, either return a copy or don't provide the functionality to return such an object."